# PHP Mysql how to get results in same Rows if the months is same

Tags: mysql, sql

I am in big trouble and I need your help, I have two tables sales and recovery. My requirement is to get report month wise so I use date_format in query with Union All, its working fine but the issue is its shows the result in different rows of sale and recovery if the month is same.

Sale:

```
ID(unique)  Party    Amount    Sale_Date
1            95      1500      01-05-2017
2            97      3500      15-05-2017
3            95      2500      05-06-2017
4            97      500       10-06-2017
5            99      1000      01-07-2017
```

Recovery:

```
ID(unique)  Party    Amount    Recovery_Date
1            95      1000      01-06-2017
2            97      2000      20-06-2017
3            95      3500      10-07-2017
4            97      900       10-07-2017
5            99      1500      15-08-2017
```

I want to get result month wise so I use DATE_FORMAT in query with UNION ALL. below is the query i am using.

```
"SELECT SUM(amount) as sale_amount, DATE_FORMAT(Sale_Date, '%M %Y'), 
null as recovery_amount FROM 
`SALE` GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Sale_Date, '%M %Y')
UNION ALL
"SELECT null as sale_amount, DATE_FORMAT(Sale_Date, '%M %Y'), 
SUM(amount) as recovery_amount FROM 
`SALE` GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Sale_Date, '%M %Y')
```

**Result:**

```
S.No    Month     Sale    Recovery    Balance
 1      May-2017  5000                5000
 2      June-2017 3000                3000
 3      June-2017         3000        -3000
 4      July-2017 1000                1000
 5      July-2017         4400        -4400
 6      Aug-2017          1500        -1500
```

the above result is ok but i need the result in below format to get correct balance amount

**Expected Result:**

```
S.No    Month     Sale    Recovery    Balance
 1      May-2017  5000                5000
 2      June-2017 3000    3000        0
 3      July-2017 1000    4400        -3300
 4      Aug-2017          1500        -1500
```

Comment: how ? can you please create the query for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to aggregate the resultsof the union by moving it into a subquery:

```
Select year_month, sum(sale_amount) as sale_amount, sum(recover_amount) as recovery_amount, sum(sale_amount)-sum(recovery_amount) as balance
From (
            SELECT SUM(amount) as sale_amount, DATE_FORMAT(Sale_Date, '%M %Y') as year_month, null as recovery_amount
            FROM `SALE` GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Sale_Date, '%M %Y')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT null as sale_amount, DATE_FORMAT(recovery_Date, '%M %Y'), SUM(amount) as recovery_amount 
            FROM `recovery` GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(recovery_Date, '%M %Y')) as t
Group by year_month
```

Unfortunately, mysql does not support full outer join hence this beauty above.